# Cocoa: get path to Contents/Resources folder in cocoa bundle

Tags: c++, cocoa, resources

I am aware of how to get a specific file from the Resources folder in cocoa, i.e. :

```
NSBundle* myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString* myImage = [myBundle pathForResource:@"Seagull" ofType:@"jpg"];
```

anyways, I'd like to have a simple function that gives me the path to the Resources folder so I can use it in c++ like this.

```
String getResourcePath()
{
    return the correct path here
}

std::ofstream theFile;
theFile.open(getResourcePath()+"test.txt");
```

I guess I could manually combine the main bundle name with Contents/Resources, anyways I'd like to know if there is a more robust solution!

Thanks!

Answer (score -9, accepted):

If you ever wonder if an Apple-provided class has a certain method, **do look up Apple's own documentation** before asking the question here at SO.

In this case, the answer is [this method](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-resourcePath). But let me reiterate:

If you ever wonder if an Apple-provided class has a certain method, **do look up Apple's own documentation** before asking the question here at SO.

And, when you do so, **go over all the methods in the documentation.** That way, you'll learn what kind of methods are available.

Comment: Sorry if I might have offended you; but there are just too many questions at SO like this ... :p

Comment: @Yuji when you answer a question on SO, you're answering it for everyone not just the OP. Telling people to just look at the Apple docs and then linking to a 55 page documents doesn't really help if you arrived here from a Google search...

Comment: @Jamie Thanks, you're definitely right. But reading through all 55 pages make also make you definitely a good Cocoa programmer.